# Function template specialisation of overloaded function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename A, typename B> void test(A a, B b) { cout << "first" << endl;}

template <typename A> void test(A a, int b) { cout << "second" << endl;}

template <> void test(int a, int b) { cout << "special" << endl;} //this is a specific instantiation, of which template?

int main(){

    test(2,3); //got: "special"
    test<int>(2,3); //got: "special"
    test<int, int>(2,3); //got: "first". So specialisation is linked to second template, why?
}
```

What is the rule for selecting which template the explicit specialization is an instantiation of? It seems like it could be ambiguous. From the output of the last function call it is indicated to me that the specialisation is for the second function template definition (the explicit template arguments select the first template, but the specialisation is not used - so it must be a specialisation of the second template), why exactly? It seems like any relevant info should be in [14.7.3] of N3337 but to the best of my ability I could not find what I was looking for. Might the program even be in error by doing this?

Granted it might be rare that someone would have to worry about this but I'm still curious as to why it happens.

Comment: After deduction for all candidates, partial ordering is performed ([temp.deduct.decl]/2), which selects the second template as more specialized.

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) has the relevant information, but I'm still working through the steps in my head, so I can't summarize it.

Comment: @Columbo yeah that's it, I was looking in the wrong place. Also found a [relevant thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233519/function-specialized-template-problem?rq=1).